# Spotlight and QuickLook integration

Tags: macos, spotlight, quicklook, spotlight-plugin

I wrote an app which document type is a bundle. This bundle contains 5 internal files, one of them is a HTML with the document "itself". I would like to make my app Spotlight and Quick Look enabled. Is there an easy way to tell the application "for Spotlight and QuickLook pretend you are the HTML file inside the bundle"? Or I have to write the plugins?

Regards, Kurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write plug-ins (for Quick Look, you could try using special symlinks inside your bundle but they won't work with HTML files IIRC).

Your Quick Look plug-in will likely be very simple since you can use `QLThumbnailRequestSetThumbnailWithURLRepresentation` (tells Quick Look to produce your thumbnail by rendering your HTML file) and `QLPreviewRequestSetURLRepresentation` (which tells Quick Look to use your HTML file for the preview.

Answer (score 0):

To get Spotlight to index your document you must write an mdimporter, but all it needs to do is run `/System/Library/Spotlight/RichText.mdimporter` on your HTML file with the parameters given to your importer.